# Creating typemaps for SWIG so C function can return a Lua table

Tags: c, lua, swig, lua-table, typemaps

I'm trying to wrap a C function which creates float array and then return this array as Lua table so it can be used in Lua.

Here's the C function that returns float array with 4 elements.

```
static void getArray(int size, float values[4]) {

    for (int i=0; i<size; ++i)
        values[i] = (float)i;
}
```

And this is the typemaps part in .i file.

```
// using typemaps
%include <typemaps.i>
%apply (float OUTPUT[ANY]) {(float values[4])};
```

And in Lua, I can use the function as the following,

```
arr = my.getArray(4); //table "arr" is now {0,1,2,3}
```

While this works fine, I wonder if it is possible to create a C function that can return a mutable float array.

So I think the function will look like this.

```
static void getArray(int size, float **values) {

    //create a float array and then return this as a table in Lua. 
}
```

However, I don't know how to bind this function with SWIG interface(.i).

I tried everything I can do but couldn't make it to work so far.

Can anyone please guide me how to wrap this function using SWIG so I can return a mutable float array as a table in Lua?

P.S: Here's the link to the Lua SWIG documentation.
http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Lua.html

**------------------------ADDED BELOW------------------------**

@Flexo Based on your updated solution, I could successfully bind `getArray` function which looks like the following.

```
static void getArray(const string &name, int *size, t_word **values) {

        t_garray *a;
        int vecsize;
        t_word *vec;

        if (getArrayData(name, &a, &vecsize, &vec)) {

            *values = vec;
            *size = vecsize;
        }
    }
```

And this is my SWIG interface.

```
%typemap(in,numinputs=0) (int *size, t_word **values) (t_word *tmp=NULL, int tsize=0) %{
  $2 = &tmp; // Use the temporary we setup
  $1 = &tsize;
%}

%typemap(argout) (int *size, t_word **values) {

  int i;
  lua_newtable(L);
  for (i = 0; i < *$1; i++){
    lua_pushnumber(L,(lua_Number)(*$2)[i].w_float);
    lua_rawseti(L,-2,i+1);/* -1 is the number, -2 is the table*/
  }
  SWIG_arg++;
}
```

`t_word` is a struct used for array which has a float data `w_float`.

I didn't need to free anything as I didn't allocate new memory and it seems to work like a charm.

Thank you so much for your help. I learned a lot from your code.

Comment: your question don't make sense, if you want return something in C your function prototype should look like that: `float *getArray(int size);` or `int getArray(int size, float **result);`. You are confusing basic rule of C, function parameter are local.

Comment: @Stargateur Thanks I edited my question. How should I edit the typemaps so it can return a float array? Maybe it's not possible with SWIG?

Comment: I believe the doc in "23.4.4 Typemaps and pointer-pointer functions" will answer you.

Comment: @Stargateur Thanks. I tried the doc by changing `iMath` to `float` but couldn't make it to work. If I call `ok,ptr=Create_Math()` in Lua, I get number for `ok` which is a returned value from c function but `nil` for `ptr` which should give a table of numbers instead. I just simplified my question a bit.

Comment: Can you show the use-case?  I don't really understand what you mean by “return a mutable float array”.  The solution you currently have seems to work fine?  Where do you find it to be lacking?

Comment: @HenriMenke I think the problem is that the array size has to be fixed at compile time with the current solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a multi-argument typemap. I based mine on the ones for OUTPUT[ANY] in typemaps.i and put together a quick test to show how it might work:

```c
%module test

%typemap(in,numinputs=1) (int size, float **values) (float *tmp=NULL) %{
  $2 = &tmp; // Use the temporary we setup
  // Either of the next two lines are equivalent 
  //$1 = (int)lua_tonumber(L,$input);
  $typemap(in,int);
%}

%typemap(freearg) (int size, float **values) %{
  free(tmp$argnum); // Assuming this is the right semantics here
%}

%typemap(argout) (int size, float **values) {
  // Adapted from OUTPUT[ANY] argout in typemaps.i 
  int i;
  lua_newtable(L);
  for (i = 0; i < $1; i++){
    lua_pushnumber(L,(lua_Number)(*$2)[i]);
    lua_rawseti(L,-2,i+1);/* -1 is the number, -2 is the table*/ \
  }
  SWIG_arg++;
}

%inline %{
static void getArray(int size, float **values) {
    //create a float array and then return this as a table in Lua.
    float *arr = malloc(sizeof *arr * size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        arr[i] = i;
    } 
    *values = arr;
}
```

From Lua we can use this function like this:

```lua
Lua 5.3.3  Copyright (C) 1994-2016 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> l=require('test')
> l
table: 0xcb87de8
> l.getArray()
stdin:1: Error in getArray expected 1..1 args, got 0
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'test.getArray'
        stdin:1: in main chunk
        [C]: in ?
> l.getArray(1)
table: 0xcb86d48
> l.getArray(1)
table: 0xcb88b50
> l.getArray(1)[0]
nil
> l.getArray(1)[1]
0.0
> l.getArray(1)[2]
nil
> l.getArray(3)[2]
1.0
> l.getArray(3)[3]
2.0
> l.getArray(3)[4]
nil
>
```

Most of the work here is in the argout typemap, which creates a new table and populates it with the values that our `getArray()` function placed into the `float **` output parameter.

If the real version of `getArray()` doesn't actually let you specify or find out the length of the output then you're better off not wrapping that at all and focusing on wrapping `getArrayData()` itself. (You can use `%rename` to make the interface feel more similar for users already familiar with the C++ API if desired though). To wrap `getArrayData()` I'd change this to be something like:

```
%module test
%include <std_string.i>
%typemap(in,numinputs=0) (int *size, float **values) (float *tmp=NULL,int tsize=0) %{
  $2 = &tmp;
  $1 = &tsize;
%}

%typemap(argout) (int *size, float **values) {
  // Adapted from OUTPUT[ANY] argout in typemaps.i 
  int i;
  lua_newtable(L);
  for (i = 0; i < *$1; i++){
    lua_pushnumber(L,(lua_Number)(*$2)[i]);
    lua_rawseti(L,-2,i+1);/* -1 is the number, -2 is the table*/ \
  }
  SWIG_arg++;
}

%inline %{
static void getArrayData(const std::string& name, void *something_else, int *size, float **values) {
    // pretend like someone already owns this memory
    static float arr[100]; 
    *size = sizeof arr / sizeof *arr;
    for (int i = 0; i < *size; ++i) {
        arr[i] = i;
    } 
    *values = arr;
}
%}
```

Key changes:

- No need for freearg typemap now as we're not actually allocating any memory
- numinputs=0 because both `int *size` and `float **values` are outputs
- An extra local variable for the size output inside the typemap

Comment: Hey Thanks you so much. I tried this and it works very well. However, could you please also teach me how to create typemap if the array size is also set internally? The actual function I'm trying to bind looks like the following. `static void getArray(const std::string &name, float **values) {
        
        int size;
        float *arr;
 getArrayWithName(name, &size, &arr); 
 *values = arr;
}`

Comment: When you call `getArray()` in C how do you know how long the array it has allocated for you is?

Comment: Hi, I edited my original post. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @ZackLee  - I've added an update. Basically I wouldn't touch `getArray()` in SWIG at all now and would call directly into `getArrayData()`. You could also use `%inline` quite sensibly here and avoid the typemaps entirely. (It would have been much easier if you had that detail from the start though)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and I'm sorry for the inconvenience. I thought I could modify the code myself for my needs but it was more complicated than I thought.

Comment: I'd appreciate if you could have a look at my other question I just posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50703758/proper-way-to-free-a-pointer-array-in-swig-input-typemap