# Proper way to free a pointer array in SWIG input typemap?

Tags: pointers, lua, swig, lua-table, typemaps

Hi I'm trying to wrap the following function using SWIG.

```
static void readTable(int argc, t_atom *argv) { //accepts table in Lua e.g. readTable({"ab",3});

        for (int i=0; i<argc; ++i) {

            if (argv[i].a_type == A_FLOAT)
                printf("FLOAT : %g\n", argv[i].a_w.w_float);
            else if (argv[i].a_type == A_SYMBOL)
                printf("SYMBOL : %s\n", argv[i].a_w.w_symbol->s_name);
        }
    }
```

Here's the typemap I created.

```
%include "exception.i"
%typemap(in) (int argc, t_atom *argv)
{
    if (!lua_istable(L, 1)) {
      SWIG_exception(SWIG_RuntimeError, "argument mismatch: table expected");
    }
    lua_len(L, 1);
    $1 = lua_tointeger(L, -1);
    $2 = (t_atom *)getbytes($1 * sizeof(t_atom)); //internally calls calloc()

    for (int i=0; i<$1; ++i) {

        lua_pushinteger(L, i+1);
        lua_gettable(L, 1);

        if(lua_isnumber(L, -1)) {

            $2[i].a_type = A_FLOAT;
            $2[i].a_w.w_float = lua_tonumber(L, -1);
        }          
        else if(lua_isstring(L, -1)) {

            $2[i].a_type = A_SYMBOL;
            $2[i].a_w.w_symbol = gensym(lua_tostring(L, -1));
        }
    }
    freebytes($2, $1 * sizeof(t_atom)); //internally calls free()
}
```

As you can see, I allocate memory for an array using `getbytes()` which internally calls `calloc()` and free the memory using `freebytes()` which internally calls `free()`.

Surprisingly, when I call `readTable()` function in Lua, it works fine without crashing.

for example, calling `test.readTable({3, "abc"})` in Lua prints the following result.

```
FLOAT : 3
SYMBOL : abc
```

My questions are

a) How can `readTable()` print results without crashing when I freed the memory in SWIG interface? Maybe memory is not being properly freed?

b) If a) doesn't make sense or is not safe to use, would you recommend calling the `freebytes()` inside the function `readTable()` instead so it can be like the following?

```
static void readTable(int argc, t_atom *argv) {

        for (int i=0; i<argc; ++i) {

            if (argv[i].a_type == A_FLOAT)
                post("FLOAT : %g", argv[i].a_w.w_float);
            else if (argv[i].a_type == A_SYMBOL)
                post("SYMBOL : %s", argv[i].a_w.w_symbol->s_name);
        }
        freebytes(argv, argc * sizeof(t_atom));
    }
```

Comment: Is this C or C++? My answer to b) depends largely on that.

Comment: @Flexo It's C++.

Comment: @Flexo Could you please read the 3rd comment below the answer? I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is exactly the situation which [`%typemap(freearg)`](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Typemaps.html#Typemaps_nn33) is for.

```cpp
%include "exception.i"

%typemap(in) (int argc, t_atom *argv) {
    if (!lua_istable(L, $input)) {
        SWIG_exception(SWIG_RuntimeError, "argument mismatch: table expected");
    }
    lua_len(L, $input);
    $1 = lua_tointeger(L, -1);
    $2 = (t_atom *)getbytes($1 * sizeof(t_atom)); // internally calls calloc()

    for (int i = 0; i < $1; ++i) {

        lua_pushinteger(L, i + 1);
        lua_gettable(L, $input);

        if (lua_isnumber(L, -1)) {
            $2[i].a_type = A_FLOAT;
            $2[i].a_w.w_float = lua_tonumber(L, -1);
        } else if (lua_isstring(L, -1)) {
            $2[i].a_type = A_SYMBOL;
            $2[i].a_w.w_symbol = gensym(lua_tostring(L, -1));
        } else {
            SWIG_exception(SWIG_RuntimeError, "unhandled argument type");
        }
    }
}

%typemap(freearg) (int argc, t_atom *argv) {
    freebytes($2, $1 * sizeof(t_atom)); // internally calls free()
}

static void readTable(const std::string &name, int argc, t_atom *argv);
```

This is the generated code from SWIG 3.0

```cpp
static int _wrap_readTable(lua_State* L) {
  int SWIG_arg = 0;
  std::string *arg1 = 0 ;
  int arg2 ;
  t_atom *arg3 = (t_atom *) 0 ;

  SWIG_check_num_args("readTable",2,2)
  if(!lua_isuserdata(L,1)) SWIG_fail_arg("readTable",1,"std::string const &");

  if (!SWIG_IsOK(SWIG_ConvertPtr(L,1,(void**)&arg1,SWIGTYPE_p_std__string,0))){
    SWIG_fail_ptr("readTable",1,SWIGTYPE_p_std__string);
  }

  {
    if (!lua_istable(L, 2)) {
      SWIG_exception(SWIG_RuntimeError, "argument mismatch: table expected");
    }
    lua_len(L, 2);
    arg2 = lua_tointeger(L, -1);
    arg3 = (t_atom *)getbytes(arg2 * sizeof(t_atom)); // internally calls calloc()

    for (int i = 0; i < arg2; ++i) {
      lua_pushinteger(L, i + 1);
      lua_gettable(L, 2);

      if (lua_isnumber(L, -1)) {
        arg3[i].a_type = A_FLOAT;
        arg3[i].a_w.w_float = lua_tonumber(L, -1);
      } else if (lua_isstring(L, -1)) {
        arg3[i].a_type = A_SYMBOL;
        arg3[i].a_w.w_symbol = gensym(lua_tostring(L, -1));
      } else {
        SWIG_exception(SWIG_RuntimeError, "unhandled argument type");
      }
    }
  }
  readTable((std::string const &)*arg1,arg2,arg3);

  {
    freebytes(arg3, arg2 * sizeof(t_atom)); // internally calls free()
  }
  return SWIG_arg;

  if(0) SWIG_fail;

fail:
  {
    freebytes(arg3, arg2 * sizeof(t_atom)); // internally calls free()
  }
  lua_error(L);
  return SWIG_arg;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I will give you 50 point tomorrow.

Comment: @ZackLee Probably you noticed that I added an `else` branch in the table conversion to prevent a segmentation fault.

Comment: Hey, `readTable(int argc, t_atom *argv)` works fine but when I add one more argument to the function e.g. `readTable(const string &name, int argc, t_atom *argv)`, It throws an error  `SWIG_RuntimeError:argument mismatch: table expected` when I call `readTable("name", table)` in Lua. Would it be possible to correct the typemap so it can only recognize `int argc, t_atom *argv` as a table and bypass other arguments as they should be?

Comment: @ZackLee I don't know and it might not be possible.  SWIG typemaps rely on simply pattern matching of function signatures, see http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Typemaps.html#Typemaps_multi_argument_typemaps_patterns

Comment: But when I used `%apply (float *INPUT, int) {(float *values, int size)};` I could successfully pass a table to the function `void setArray(const string &name, float *values, int size)` by calling `setArray("name", table)` in Lua. So I hope it should be possible.

Comment: `%apply` is only for copying typemaps, not for partial matching, see http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Typemaps.html#Typemaps_nn48

Comment: Thanks. Could you please give me a hint on how to write typemap for `readTable(const string &name, int argc, t_atom *argv)`? I tried adding the string argument and simply changed `$1` to `$2` and `$2` to `$3` but I failed to do `readTable("name", table)` in Lua. How to design the typemap so the function can accept 1 string and 1 table?

Comment: @ZackLee not sure I follow here, typemaps should be applied independently to each and every argument they match (even multi-argument ones)

Comment: On this answer you might need to be a bit careful with the freearg typemap in the error case, depending on what your `freebytes` function really does internally. `free()` is fine on a null pointer, but if your own function here isn't for whatever reason you'll need to check that.

Comment: @Flexo You said typemaps should be applied independently to each and every argument they match then why `readTable(const string &name, int argc, t_atom *argv)`can't be used in Lua when it works fine with `readTable(int argc, t_atom *argv)`?

Comment: @ZackLee Well, the table is no longer the first argument, but the second, so you have to adjust the check inside the typemap from `if (!lua_istable(L, 1))` to `if (!lua_istable(L, $input))`, see also the updated answer.

Comment: @HenriMenke Hey Thank you so much for your help. Now it works like a charm. I can't thank you enough. So does $input converts to the number of arguments passed to the function in Lua? In this case 2?

Comment: @HenriMenke The bounty giving option has disappeared again. Is it not possible to give out a bounty once I select an answer? Is there anyway I can give you one?

Comment: @ZackLee As soon as there is an answer to the question, the minimum bounty is raised from 50 to 100.

Comment: @ZackLee By the way, since you are interfacing C++ with Lua you might be interested in [sol2](https://github.com/ThePhD/sol2).  It an abstraction for the Lua C API rather than an interface generator like SWIG.  Hence it requires a little more work for simple functions, but binding more complex things is much easier.  There was a talk at C++Now about it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Lwy4_sKeJM

Comment: @ZackLee `$input` is a SWIG generic thing that in all languages expands to the thing you were given as an argument from Python or Java or C# or Lua. Lua is a bit special though with the stack module, so instead of being a variable like most languages you just get an offset into the stack.